# VNC ISPSystem glitches on high resolution

Tags: vnc, isp

I am trying to perform an installation of Android x86 8.1 RC2 on VPS through the means of ISP panel, via VNC.  Here is what I see in any VNC client (noVNC, VNC Viewer):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPc5x.jpg]

Such a bug only appears after the initial installation, after the boot menu. It looks like when the resolution has changed into the higher one, it occurs.  I wonder if anyone encountered the similar issue.  I also wonder how I can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Boot Menu -> Tab -> vga=ask

https://linuxhint.com/set_screen_resolution_linux_kernel_boot/